# Is there a standard calculation for "degree of irregularity" of heartbeat?

Tags: heart-rate

I'm considering making an online tool to help calculate the degree of irregularity of heartbeat. I'd like to use a standard measurement and formula if such a thing exists.

For example a user taps a button along with their heartbeat to get an idea of how regular or irregular the beating is. It would show the degree to which the space between the beats is the same.

Perhaps this is just a standard deviation calculation? Or variance?

Comment: Questions here are required to demonstrate some degree of prior research. To get you started, I suggest looking up R-R interval.